# Cisco - LACP between two Catalyst switches (trunk links)

Tags: cisco, lacp

So I just put up a LACP between two Cisco catalyst switches.

Snippets of configuration are as following:

[3550 switch - port 22 and 23 are connected to 2950 and 24 is to router]

```
interface Port-channel1
 switchport access vlan 50
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode passive
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode passive
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport access vlan 50
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport voice vlan 10
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan50
 ip address 10.10.10.12 255.255.255.0
!
ip default-gateway 10.10.10.5
```

[2950 switch - port 23 and 24 are connected to 3550]

```
interface Port-channel1
 switchport access vlan 50
 switchport mode trunk
 flowcontrol send off
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 switchport access vlan 50
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode active
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode active
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan50
 ip address 10.10.10.6 255.255.255.0
 no ip route-cache
!
ip default-gateway 10.10.10.5
```

Now I did some basic "show inter trunk" and "show cdp neighbor," etc to verify. But is there a better/sure way to make sure those two links are aggregated and enhancing bandwidth between the two switches?
I wonder if that "flowcontrol" will bother things?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a "switchport access vlan 50" on the port-channel interface, but it's configured as a trunk. Perhaps you were looking for "switchport trunk native vlan 50"? It's important that the trunk native vlan are identical on both ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show etherchannel [channel-group] detail

show interfaces port-channel [channel-group]

show lacp [channel-group] counters internal neighbor

Answer (score 0):

`show etherchannel summary` lists all of the channels and their associated interfaces

`show int po##` as mentioned above shows statistics for the port-channel interface, but also lists the physical member interfaces